# Error with free() in C (invalid next size) after realloc

Tags: c, free, realloc

I've been trying to figure out what the problem is for hours and can't get it right. Here is the code, which is of course a lot longer but I've reduced it to the problem itself.

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 60
char *str;

void readText() {
    char read_char;
    int i = 0;
    str = (char *) calloc(BUFFER_SIZE, sizeof(char));
    while ((read_char = getchar()) != EOF) { /* user hits ctrl+d */
        *(str+i) = read_char;
        i++;
        if (i % BUFFER_SIZE == 0) {
            str = (char *) realloc(str, BUFFER_SIZE * sizeof(char));
        }
    }
    textSize = i;
    /* Here I print the text... same error printing or not printing */
    free(str);
}
```

}

I only get the error when the input text exceeds the buffer size.

(edited:
if (i % BUFFER_SIZE == 0) so it makes it every time it get to 60, but the error is the same
)

Thanks

Comment: Buffer overflow leads to *undefined behavior*. Don't let it happen.

Comment: By the way, the [`getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) functions returns an **`int`**, which is rather important for the comparison against the `int` value `EOF`.

Comment: And on another note, for any pointer or array `p` and index `i` the expression `*(p + i)` is *exactly* equal to `p[i]`. The latter (`p[i]`) is usually easier to read and understand, and less to write.

Comment: Look at the realloc vs the original `calloc`. Is there *any* difference in the amount of memory allocated *at all* ? Um... no. And then you promptly walk off the end an breach that buffer to invoke UB. Equally bad, even if you fixed the sizing there, you need a dynamic *capacity* to be updated, not a fixed constant buffer size.

Comment: Then we have the `realloc` call itself, which doesn't reallocate anything. You just allocate the same size over and over. Just like `malloc` its size argument is the size in bytes to allocate.

Comment: And lastly, in C you [shouldn't really cast the result of `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858).

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are `realloc`ating with the same size, you need to use the new size when the string grows up:

```
while ((read_char = getchar()) != EOF) { /* user hits ctrl+d */
    if (i >= BUFFER_SIZE) {
        str = realloc(str, i);
    }
    *(str+i) = read_char;
    i++;
}
```

Also, it seems that you forget to set the trailing NUL, you need it in order to build a valid (printable) string, switch to

```
    if (i >= BUFFER_SIZE - 1) {
```

and

```
str[i] = '\0';
```

after the `while` loop.

Finally, prefer

```
size_t i = 0; // or better yet size_t len = 0;
```

over

```
int i = 0;
```

to pass the size to `realloc` and friends.

Comment: Sorry, I thought realloc adds after the end of what it has, bad understanding of it.